# how do I change the password for multiple users in groupwise?

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, novell, groupwise

I have 1000 users I need to change the user passwords to a 'known to admin' password for a migration tool (groupwise to exchange).
Admin does not have any of the user passwords.
How do I change a batch of user passwords via LDAP or other management protocol when admin does not have the existing user passwords?
All users are in the Groupwise LDAP directory and not system level on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ldapsearch which is the easiest. The -ZZ assist with authentication which I had to use.
ldapsearch -x -ZZ -h localhost -D "cn=admin,o=RealmOrDomain" -b o=RealmOrDomain

will dump just about everything

ldapsearch -x -ZZ -h localhost -D "cn=admin,o=RealmOrDomain" -b o=RealmOrDomain mail |grep mail:

If you need a more specific search

Answer (score 0):

There simply isn't enough information here to be able to answer your question. It would help to know the version of GroupWise. And you also mentioned LDAP.  GroupWise can use authentication either via LDAP or via GroupWise native passwords.  If you are indeed using LDAP passwords for your GroupWise account, then it really isn't a GroupWise question. It's a question of what LDAP server you are using for the password source.  In other words, it would be different if we are talking about GroupWise passwords, AD passwords, or eDirectory passwords.  Also, if it is GroupWise 2014, the way to manage GroupWise passwords themselves would be much simplified.  So, give us a little more information.

Thanks

Danita Zanre 
Caledonia.net

Comment: groupwise uses ldap by default and the solution is ldapmodify. The ldapsearch and ldapmodify are the 'backdoor/ass end' to administrating Novell and upchucking all of it's guts via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

ldapmodify has the ability to edit passwords if you have administrative access.
Ideal for batch commands too.